# Missing section numbering with classicthesis

Tags: classicthesis

As soon as I include the `classicthesis` package, all section (and sub[sub]section) numbers vanish. Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{a chapter with a number}
    \section{a section that should have a label}
    \section*{a section that should not have a label}
    \section{another section}
    \subsection{a subsection}
\end{document}
```

In the output, none of the sections have a leading number (but the chapter does).

I am using the most recent version (v4.2) of classicthesis [from CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/). Document class doesn't seem to make a difference; I tried both KOMA and 'classical' classes.

I use texlive on Ubuntu, and already reinstalled everything. Getting no errors or warnings in the log. And can't for the heck of it figure out why the numbering gets suppressed.

Comment: I get 1.1, no number, 1.2 and 1.2.1 as expected

Comment: Perhaps this is the `titlesec` bug issue. Try to update `titlesec`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was a buggy version of a package. Updating the package resolved the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Christian Hupfer's suggestion did the trick - I overrode the titlesec package in the texlive folder manually with the [version from CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec), and now everything works as intended.

Comment: Glad it worked. Welcome to TeX.SX by the way!